# Variáveis fazem print muitas vezes

Tags: java

As variáveis `media` e `contador`, após a execução, fazem print muitas vezes e não estou a perceber o porquê. Queria que apenas fizessem print uma vez no final da execução do código todo.

O meu código:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Chuva{
    public static void main(String[] args){

        int chuvadia;
        int [] chuva;
        int semanal;
        int quantidade;
        int y = 0;
        int i;
        double media;
        int soma = 0;
        int contador =0;
        double perc;


        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        //REGISTAR A QUANTIDADE DE CHUVA
        System.out.println("Insira a quantidade de chuva total esta semana");
        semanal = input.nextInt();

        //
        chuva = new int[7];

        if(semanal < 0){
            System.out.println("A quantidade de chuva nao pode ser negativa");
        } else {

        for(i = 0; i<chuva.length; i++){
                System.out.println("Indique a quantidade de chuva no dia" + y);
                y++;
                chuvadia = input.nextInt();

                if(chuvadia < 0){
                    System.out.println("A chuva nao pose ser negativa");
                    break;
                } else {

                chuva[i] = chuvadia;
                }
        }

        for(i = 0; i<chuva.length; i++){
            soma+= chuva[i];
        }
        media = (soma/7);
        System.out.println("A media e de:" + media);

        for(i=0;i<chuva.length;i++){
            double max = chuva[0];
            if( chuva[i] > max){
                max = chuva[i];
                System.out.println("O maior e:" + max);
            }

        }
        }
        for(i=0;i<chuva.length;i++){
            perc = (chuva[i]/semanal);
            if(perc < 0.2){
                contador++;
            }
            System.out.println("O n de dias com perc de chuva menor que 20% da semanal e:" + contador);
        }



}
}
```

Comment: Ué, o `System.out.println` está dentro de um `for`, aí aparece várias vezes mesmo

Comment: É isso, obrigado! Agora tenho outro erro, ao executar não esta a dar o maximo correto aqui:

 for(i=0;i<chuva.length;i++){
            double max = chuva[0];
            if( chuva[i] > max){
                max = chuva[i];
                System.out.println("O maior e:" + max);
            } 

Sabe porque?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O `System.out.println` está dentro de um `for`, aí aparece várias vezes mesmo.

> Por: [@Sorack](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/59479/sorack)

Answer (score 0):

> Agora tenho outro erro, ao executar não esta a dar o maximo correto
>   aqui: for(i=0;i
>
> > max){ max = chuva[i]; System.out.println("O maior e:" + max); } Sabe porque?

O problema é sua variavel max que está pegando sempre a primeira posicao do array chuva.